# Windows Phone 8 restarting from tombstone state

Tags: windows-phone-8, restart, resume

In my app, I'd haven't implemented any deactivate/resume code yet. The app will restart fine if it's deactivated and then reactivated, but if I mark 'Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging' in the debug settings, I get a 'Resuming' message that lasts forever. I was expecting for the app to start fresh in this case. Do I need to implement serialization to even get the app to correctly start from tombstone? Or can I force it to fresh start somehow.